# Component doen't re-render when the state is changed

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.
I have a state `songs`, and its setState function: `setSongs()`. And I have a context provider, named SongContext:

```
const [songs, setSongs] = useState(props.data.songs);
return (
    <SongContext.Provider value={{ songs, setSongs }}>
        {songs.map((row) => {
            return (...);   //child components
        }}
    </SongContext.Provider>
);
```

Inside the child component of this context provider, I have a function:

```
const { songs, setSongs } = useContext(SongContext);
const removeSong = async () => {
    const data = {
        playlistId: props.playlistId,
        songId: props.songId,
    };

    const res = await axios.post("api/deleteSongFromPlaylist", data);
    if (res.data.status === 200) {
        for (var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
            if (songs[i].songId === data.songId) {
                let tmpSongs = songs;
                tmpSongs.splice(i, 1);
                setSongs(tmpSongs);
                console.log(songs);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else ...
};
```

I want the parent component that containing context provider to re-render and remove the song when `removeSong()` is triggered.
Problem is: When this `removeSong()` function is triggered, `setSongs()` function updates the `songs` value, `console.log()` right after this shows me that the `songs` value is already changed. But the parent component containing context provider is still not re-rendered.
Why? And how to solve this problem ?

Comment: how about to update state by `setSongs([...tmpSongs]);`?

Comment: Oh, it's work. Can you briefly explain it?

Comment: React can detect that a state changed by comparing its value. When the state is represented by an object (or an array), React will not inspect the object. It only makes an equality. So you need to create a new object (or array) if you want it to detect the change. That’s what @SaeedShamloo is doing in his solution.

Comment: as @StéphaneVeyret described, you need to generate new array and since splice method mutates array directly, react can not realize changing in the state. Thank you Stéphane.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent many hours with it. I didn't expect the solution is so simple :D